# How to bind the Textarea value to the model data field

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, model

In my view I have an textarea box where the user will write a comment

```
Comment: @Html.TextArea("comment1", new { style ="width:200px; height:15px;"});
```

And I have added a field in my model about it :

```
 public class Transactions
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int OrganisationId { get; set; }
        public string Comment1 { get; set; }
    }
```

So now I want to bind the Comment1 field with the text area value comment1. So whatever the user writes in the @Html.TextArea to be saved in the database.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `TextAreaFor` instead:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(
model => model.comment1, 
new { style = "width: 200px; height: 15px;" }
)
```

Be certain to reference your model in your view, as well.

Comment: So this will get the input on the text area and save it into the comment1 or I still need to make a function on that?

Sorry for the silly questions. I am learning by doing :/

Comment: This will include the value of comment1 in the form action. You can post the form back to the controller, and then do the validation and saving through the appropriate controller action, referencing the bound field through the model.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you include your model in your view (ex @model Transactions)
Then try:
Comment: @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Comment1, new { ... }) 

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.textareaextensions.textareafor(v=vs.118).aspx